# Navigation.PushAsync not working as expected in .NET Maui

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I've got an app that I am porting over to Maui from XF. I have a toolbaritem in my navigationbar. Here is the basic definition:

```
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="New Game" Clicked="NewGame_Clicked" x:Name="NewGame" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <VerticalStackLayout><ListView........./></VerticalStackLayout>
```

Here is my NewGame_Clicked Event:

```
    private void NewGame_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new EventSetupPage());
    }
```

Here is the content of the EventSetupPage() overly simplified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ScanAndScoringMauiApp.Pages.EventSetupPage"
             Title="EventSetupPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

When the EventSetupPage() comes up, it is blank in an android 12 emulator. The constructor is called, so I know that something is happening. It's like the page is being loaded in the wrong thread. I'm doing something wrong. Any thoughts on what I should do to get my page to load? TIA

********** update 1 ************
As an fyi, I am loading the parent page via a messagecenter message.  I do this in my xamarin forms app.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "UpdateMainPage", (sender) =>
{
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new GameList());
    });
});
```

Comment: The first test to try is to make `EventSetupPage` the FIRST page in the Shell. (Arrange XAML so it is first.) If that comes up blank, then it is a problem specific to that page, not a navigation problem. This is usually the case.

Comment: thanks.  It's not a shell app.  The EventSetupPage comes up just fine if I make it the main page in the startup method of the app.

Comment: Add to question the lines of code you use to display the first page (in the "broken" scenario). Something like `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new YourMainPage());`?  `EventSetupPage` works if you change that to `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new EventSetupPage());`?

Comment: yes, if I set MainPage = new NavigationPage(new EventSetupPage()); the page loads as I expect.  I'm in another page so I would expect my page to come up.

Comment: My "parent" page is loaded via a call to a message.  Updated code above.  wondering if this is some threading issue, but I do try to put this on the main thread.  If I'm stupid and need to do something else, please say so.  :-)

Comment: May I confirm that are you using `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new GameList())` in your App.xaml.cs as an initial page?

Comment: Are you using `VS 17.3.5`? If so, please help create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via Github link.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Thank you for the suggestions.  yes, I am using a line in my app startup of MainPage = new NavigationPage(New GameList());.  I am using 17.3.5.  I decided to uninstall my preview and existing VS 2022 and then reinstalled just the 17.3.5.  I have created a mre (I love that concept).  the MRE works exactly as intended.  I'm going to keep at looking at what I am doing to see if there is a problem in threading.  This feels like a threading issue.  I'll keep at it.  :-)